# What is the difference when we added 'to be' in the sentence?

Tags: grammar

1. He seems to be an honest man.
2. He seems an honest man.

What is the difference when we added 'to be' in the sentence in meaning?
And What is 'to-be deletion'?

Comment: Are you asking about meaning or about grammaticality? Sentence 2 seems grammatically unacceptable to me, at least in my version of American English.

Comment: This seems like a variation on the other question you posted: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/327728/i-want-to-know-whether-to-has-subjective-meaning-or-objective. Can you consolidate them?

Comment: @curious-proofreader, I speak American English and it sounds fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/seem), "seem" can be used as a linking verb (like to be, to become, etc.) or followed with "to + infinitive".

As a ***linking verb***, it is usually followed by an adjective:

One could say "*He seems honest*" where "honest" as an adjective would describe "He" and the fact that "he" is a man is implied.

But it can also be followed by a noun or nominal group like "an honest man".

It is however significantly less common and in that case we tend to use the more versatile ***"seems to + infinitive"*** construct: "He seems to have a lot of...", "He seems to drink...", or "He seems to be an honest man".

Personally, I would use "He seems to be an honest man" if I wanted to add some emphasis.